# Simple Questions using Fragments

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-button

Trying to work on a UI whereby the user is asked 5 questions and must answer yes or no.

Want to use fragments to display the questions so when user clicks on either yes or no the next question is displayed.

At the end the yes/no values are added up and displayed.

Any tips/links for this been trying last few days and frustrated!

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are a complex solution for this. I'd consider using a custom view instead and you can save yourself some hassle. If you really want to use fragments then you could use Jetpack Navigation component with a ViewModel tied to the activity to count the answers.

Comment: Yeah I am worried that Ive been over complicating things, can I use this to gather the data from the buttons also?

Answer (score 0):

You can use swipe disabled viewpager and change the page on button click.